# AWS site-to-site VPN connection redundancy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-site-to-site

Currently, we are building a web service (on AWS) that uses a third-party service. That third-party service only allowed local VPN connection. So we connected that third-party application from our aws infrastructure via a site-to-site VPN like below.

[image]

But local VPN service providers are not so reliable. So we want to make redundancy on the local VPN connection. We want to set up a secondary site-to-site VPN connection to that new VPN service provider (B). We want to switch the VPN connection from A to B if A is down.

[image]

How could we achieve this using aws (VPN connection switching)?

Comment: Please check this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/vpn-redundant-connection.html